# Why my CreationView.json cant read setttings.json file

Tags: kaizala-action

CreationView.json cant read setttings.json file
it can load form action and data in Kaizala

Comment: Hi Tran, welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide little more details before we could help out.

Comment: Please provide more details with your code and specific issue

Answer (score 0):

I try to follow this to build Employee helpdesk

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qz9jK.png) helpdesk action

but following the code it will load settings.json file to show the action in form but i cant

[Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkQq7.png)

im not change any code in file just follow the instruction.